# How do you make websites remember numbers after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment, backend

I have a verrryy simple webpage with a button that increases a counter by 1. The number goes back to zero when the page is reloaded. How would it be possible to have the number remain where it was left? Does it require some kind of basic back end or database?

I'm new to the practicalities of web development so I'm not really sure how the backend and front end interact.

Comment: A database is one option to store on the server side. Local storage to store on the client side.

Comment: Simplest option is to use `localStorage`

Comment: I would also go for `localStorage` if the user is anonymous, if you already have a login system in place and want a counter per user then the database is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways you could do it. Like you said you could put it in a database, or you could store it in a cookie, or on the server in a session variable, or you could use localstorage.

If you want to start learning some server side stuff maybe check out a PHP (or whatever) tutorial. Using a database to store it is another layer on top of that.

If you want to just stay client side use javascript and either localstorage or the cookie option. localstorage is the newer and cooler option.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on scope, session , user/browser, user, request?

If you need to keep the value on page reload you can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), it will keep your counter until you close the page.

```
// Get counter from session storage or set it to 0
var mynum = sessionStorage.getItem('counter') | 0 ;

//... then increment
mynum ++;
// And save back to session storage
sessionStorage.setItem('counter',mynum)
```